# Connect Ultrasonic Sensor to Jetson Xavier NX

Tags: python, nvidia, nvidia-jetson, arduino-ultra-sonic

I have a Jetson Xavier NX Board. I need to interface the ultrasonic sensor.

I used Jetson.GPIO lib to communicate through GPIO but I'm not getting any data from Jetson. I believe the GPIO pin is not powering up which shows 0V after making it HIGH.
If the problem is with GPIO Configuration then please let me know how do we configure a particular pin. Otherwise, please let me know why it is not working.
I couldn't resolve this issue. Please help me with that.

Thanks in Advance.